# Macbook Pro Late 2011 ran once but will not run again after reinstalling El Capitan OS

Tags: macos, boot, macbook-pro, reinstall

Over the weekend, I wiped my drive and reinstalled my Mac's OS using the MacOS Utilities.

Everything went fine with the reinstall, I was able to run the new OS (El Capitan) and even download Chrome.

I closed the lid on my mac (while machine still on) and went to sleep.  The next morning, I was not able to turn the machine on again.

At first, I thought it was the battery, so I charged the battery for 2 hours and tried again.  Nothing. No sound, no chime, no indications of any kind that the machine is running or trying to run.

I did notice the breath light was solid, however, after I reset NVRAM and PRAM, the breath light went off.  More importantly, the mac still wouldn't turn on.

Not sure what's going on, one day it was good and next day no life.

Please help!

Comment: How far does it get into booting? Do you get an Apple logo and then a blank grey screen or...?

Comment: Try resetting the SMC which is different to PRAM/NVRAM, see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Comment: See this [troubleshooting guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mac-wont-boot-step-step-guide-waking/). Disconnect every device possible while testing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton no apple logo, no blank grey screen

Comment: After a week of leaving the machine alone and not touching it, yesterday, I plugged the power in and hit the power button and the machine turned on.  I'm without words.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the power button for a long period of time until you hear a loud long beep come from the machine. This will force machine to 'hard' boot up and perform hardware checks as it does so.